# Parsing a date works in IDE but not when running from a runnable JAR file

Tags: java, datepicker, timezone, simpledateformat, parseexception

I'm having a problem with Date Parsing.

I am getting dates from JXDatePicker and need to re-format them in order to send a query to MySQL.

**the date I get from JXDatePicker is in the following format:**

```
Mon Oct 06 00:00:00 IDT 2014
```

**I use this simpledateformat to parse it :**

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

**I Also Tried:**

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

**And:**

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

95% of the time its works fine when I run it on eclipse, sometimes I get the parse error (Listed Below), but when I restart my app its working just fine on the same dates and same input.

But, when I compiled my app to a runnable jar in order to really start using it, I get the following error 100% of the times:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Oct 06 00:00:00 IDT 2014"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at DatePicker.findRequests(DatePicker.java:385)
```

it's driving me crazy !!!

anyone has an idea for me?

**I suspect its somehow connected to the TimeZone.**

thanks,

**Dave.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't *parse* the result from `JXDatePicker` at all. It allows you to get the value *directly* as a `java.util.Date` (and time zone).

Wherever possible, avoid converting to/from text. In this case, there's no need for text *anywhere* - you can get the data out of `JXDatePicker` in a "native" format, and you should do the same when specifying the value for MySQL - use a prepared statement with parameterized SQL  and call `setDate` or `setTimestamp` to specify the values.

Comment: thanks man, that's what I initially tried to do , but couldn't find how. after what you wrote I looked again , and found it :) I prefer to work with dates only in their native Long timestamp format, just thought its not possible . thanks again !